# Javascript Canvas Draw Order

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am plotting a bar chart with some series values in a javascript loop. Even though the code drawing the series values lies below the code that draws the bars, in the next iteration of the loop the text that has just been drawn gets overwritten.

You can see this effect taking place in the code below as the alert boxes appear.

Why do drawing operations on another part of the canvas overwrite something drawn previously in a completely different place?

*Update:* Someone has helpfully pointed out that using `fillRect()` hides this issue, but my question is rather: why is it happening in the first place?

```js
var exampleData = {
  "Series 1": 10,
  "Series 2": 14,
  "Series 3": 2,
  "Series 4": 12
};

var BarChart = function(options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.canvas = options.canvas;
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  this.colors = options.colors;

  this.plot = function() {
    var maxValue = 0;
    for (var categ in this.options.data) {
      maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, this.options.data[categ]);
    }

    var noBars = Object.keys(this.options.data).length;
    var barWidth = (this.canvas.height) / noBars;
    var barIdx = 0;

    for (categ in this.options.data) {
      var barLength = Math.round(this.canvas.width * this.options.data[categ] / maxValue);
      this.ctx.save();
      alert("plotting series line " + categ);
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colors[barIdx % this.colors.length];
      this.ctx.rect(30, barIdx * barWidth, barLength, barWidth);
      this.ctx.fill();
      alert("plotting series value " + categ);
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      this.ctx.font = "24px Georgia";
      this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      this.ctx.fillText(this.options.data[categ], 25, barIdx * barWidth + barWidth / 2); //will be covered in the loop's next iteration. Why?
      this.ctx.restore();
      barIdx++;
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  myCanvas.width = 800;
  myCanvas.height = 300;
  var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
  var myBarChart = new BarChart({
    canvas: myCanvas,
    seriesName: "Example Series",
    padding: 40,
    data: exampleData,
    colors: ["#D1E3F3", "#D1E3F3", "#D1E3F3", "#D1E3F3"]
  });
  myBarChart.plot();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your `this.ctx.rect(30, barIdx * barWidth, barLength, barWidth)` looks very strange. The parameters of `rect` are `(x, y, width, height)`. So why is height called `barWidth`?

Comment: Point taken. Reason: because the bar chart is horizontal, when I came to describe the bars it seemed counter-intuitive to continue referring to them that way round. If you think of a plank of wood, you always call the short dimension the width and the long dimension the length, irrespective of how you're holding it

Comment: I don't understand.  You're drawing over the things that you just drew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing :

```
this.ctx.rect(30, barIdx * barWidth, barLength, barWidth);
this.ctx.fill();
```

To instead use [`fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) fixes the problem:

```
this.ctx.fillRect(30, barIdx * barWidth, barLength, barWidth);
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/63cmfthq/11/) (compared to the original example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umt3s8nq/1/))

Comment: Thank you this is a good solution to the issue, but my question is actually *why* does this behaviour happen, what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained in my answer (I'll update properly in the morning, it's late where I am). But basically you're not creating a new path for each rect so the previously drawn rect are part of the same path. It's why the last number isn't hidden (see here http://jsfiddle.net/m39n8opr/)

You can create a new path before drawing each rect by using beginPath() directly before rect(). I'll update my answer with a better explanation, I'll ping you when I've done so

Comment: Thanks - the clarification about beginPath() explains why this was happening! It was redrawing all the old rectangles in each iteration of the loop at the same time as drawing the new one